# Notice: Undefined index: message

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\Untitled9.php on line 27

```
    <?php  session_start(); 
if ($_GET['message'] == "success" && $_SESSION['revisit'] == "0") {     
$_SESSION['revisit'] = "1";     ?>     
<script type="text/javascript">window.alert('Message successfully posted.');</script>     
<?php } ?>
```

Line 27 is....

```
if ($_GET['message'] == "success" && $_SESSION['revisit'] == "0") {
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if there is an item with key `message` in array `$_GET` with

```
isset($_GET['message'])
```

And the same rule is applied to the second comparison of session item. So the complete code could look like

```
if (isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] == "success" && isset($_SESSION['revisit']) && $_SESSION['revisit'] == "0") {
```

And even if anyone will propose you to use `@` instead - don't believe them. It is evil. Follow the way I proposed.

Comment: As an addition to the answer, checking if variable (or array value in this case) exists should be done with **everything** that comes from user - `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`. `$_SESSION` depends on your code, but it never hurts to check it too. Checking can be done with either [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) or [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/empty). Sometimes [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) could be used instead of `isset()`, as `isset()` returns `false` for existing variables with `NULL` value.

Comment: @binaryLV: checking if variable exists should be done with everything that comes from everywhere ;-)

Comment: zerkms, what's the point in a code like `$n = 10; if ( isset($n) ) { ... }`? Variables (and array elements) can basically come from two sources - either from a user (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_FILES`), or from the source code. If it comes from source code, it should be clear that variable exists, so there's no point to check its existence.

Comment: @binaryLV: from `everywhere` I meant not the code, but any 3rd party source, that could be not just a user. Also, yes, in some cases you need to check if key exists in an array that your function returns. `$array = somefunction();` --- what can you say about that array in runtime? Nothing.

Comment: About `$array = somefunction();` - if I use `somefunction()`, I expect it to be documented and to do what it has to do. What's the point in using function if you know, well, **nothing** about it?

Comment: @binaryLV: functions sometime returns different set of keys. Yep, that is related to bad design, but that happens often.

Comment: zerkms, well, that might be a problem, and when it arises, it has to be solved. Though, that in no way means that one should bloat whole source code with unnecessary checks. If you have to use a function that may return mixed results, then deal with it, but do not assume that every function/API is such. *P.S. Why can't I start comment with "@zerkms, "? That part just gets deleted from comments...*

Comment: @binaryLV: yep, sometimes SO also just trims the @'d username in the begin. Don't know why that happens. Anyway, don't see a reason to discuss more - in general you're right and results from custom functions should be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `notice` and not a `fatal error` which indicates you can either surpress this error by changing your `error_reporting` settings, adding a `@` in front of the line of code, or doing a check if the variable exists first.

```
if(isset($_GET['message']))
```

The last might be the most elegant, because it prevents the error instead of surpressing it. However surpressing isn't a problem here since it doesn't affect your code.

Comment: (1) Changing `error_reporting` to lower version or using `@` (which essentially sets `error_reporting` to `0`) can often lead to unexpected, unexplainable and difficult-to-debug WSOD. (2) `if ($_GET['message'])` in no way prevents an error. (3) Notices (as well as warnings and `strict`) **are errors**. The fact that they are not *fatal* just makes them technically less severe, but they are still errors that should be fixed (rather than just suppressed and ignored).

Comment: Your "simply" case will throw the same notice.

Comment: Oh, woops. Personally I surpress these errors because one of the things I like about PHP is not having to worry about stuff like this. Is there any negative effect such as slowdown or whatever I should worry about? If not I'll just keep doing things like `if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar')`.

Comment: There is **some** slowdown, when accessing non-existent variables. There's **bigger** slowdown, when using `@`. There's **huge** slowdown, when accessing them with `display_errors` turned off just to hide them from user's view. There's **giant** slowdown, when custom error handler is involved. Another decent negative effect is the fact that such code is **dirty**. It does not really matter, if you work alone and make some tiny personal blog of no importance, but such practices should be avoided in real business world.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume the `message` parameter has been set:

```
if (isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] == 'success' && ...) {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can provide a default value:

```
$message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : 'no_message';
if ($message == 'success' && ..) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] == "success" && $_SESSION['revisit'] == "0") {
```